# Vue3 + NodeMailer + TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, nodemailer

How to use Vue3 + Nodemalier with TypeScript syntax with a smtp server ?

I'm looking for some code examples. I just want to send an email by cliking the submit button.
The template vue part is ok but then the script part is a mess.

I'm not a js developper and I did this code a long time ago. (Initially I was using 'https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js" but it didn't work anymore so I would like to switch to nodemailer but I'm totally lost now with the js syntax.
A hand on this would really be appreciated.

```
  <template>
  
  <q-page padding  >
      <q-card bordered class="bg-grey-2 my-card">
        <q-card-section >
        <div class="q-pa-md" style="max-width:400px; margin:auto;">
            <div class="text-h6">Share your interactions :</div><br/>

      <q-form
        @submit="onSubmit"
        @reset="onReset"
        class="q-gutter-md"
      >
      <q-input
          filled
          v-model="name"
          label="Your name *"
          hint="Name and surname"
          lazy-rules
          :rules="[ val => val && val.length > 0 || 'Please type something.']"
       />
  
       <q-input
          filled
          type="email"
          v-model="email"
          label="Your email *"
          lazy-rules
          :rules="[
          val => /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(val) || 'Please enter a valid email address.',
          ]"
      />

      <q-input
        filled
        type="text"
        v-model="ligand"
        label="Ligand - Gene Symbol *"
        lazy-rules
        :rules="[
          val => val !== null && val !== '' || 'Please type your ligand name.',
        ]"
      />

      <q-input
        filled
        type="text"
        v-model="receptor"
        label="Receptor - Gene Symbol *"
       
      />

      <q-input
      filled
      type="text"
      v-model="origin"
      label="Tissue / Cell Line"
    />

      <q-input
        filled
        type="text"
        v-model="publication"
        label="Publication PMID / DOI"
      />


  <q-input
  v-model="text"
  label="Describe your interaction"
  filled
  type="textarea"
  :rules="[
    val => val !== null && val !== '' || 'Please, give us more details.',
  ]"
/>
        <div> 
          <q-btn label="Submit" type="submit" color="primary"/>
          <q-btn label="Reset" type="reset" color="primary" flat class="q-ml-sm" />
        </div>
      </q-form>

      <div style="text-align:center;background-color:white;margin-top:15px;border-left:solid 3px #00B4FF;border-right:solid 3px #00B4FF;" v-if="messageReturned!=''" >{{messageReturned}}</div>

    </div>

    </q-card-section>
  </q-card>
</q-page>

</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted,ref} from 'vue'
import { useQuasar } from 'quasar'
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const $q = useQuasar()
const name = ref(null)
const email = ref(null)
const ligand = ref(null)
const receptor = ref(null)
const publication = ref(null)
const origin = ref(null)
const text = ref(null)
const messageReturned = ref("")

const onSubmit =  () => { 
// async..await is not allowed in global scope, must use a wrapper

   messageReturned.value = ""

  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.server",
    port: 587,
    secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: "mail", // generated ethereal user
      pass: "password", // generated ethereal password
    },
  });

  console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
  // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@example.com>

  // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
  console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info)); 
  // send mail with defined transport object
  transporter.sendMail({
    from: '"SignalRdb Team " <fsdfs@gmail.com>', // sender address
    to: "jclab.fdsfds@gmail.com, fdsfds@gmail.com", // list of receivers
    subject: "Hello ✔", // Subject line
    text: "Hello world?", // plain text body
    html: "<b>Hello world?</b>", // html body
  }).then( 

   messageReturned.value = "Your mail has been sent successfully ! Thanks."
  
  // 
  );

 };



const onReset = () => { 
        name.value = null
        email.value = null
        origin.value = null
        ligand.value =  null
        receptor.value = null
        publication.value =  null
        text.value = null
        messageReturned.value = ""
      };

</script>


<style lang="sass" scoped>
.my-card
 // width: 100%
  padding-top: 10px 
 // margin: auto 
</style>
```

Comment: https://github.com/chiragmehta900/node-typescript-boilerplate-mongoose/blob/master/src/services/mailService.ts

Comment: https://www.mystickynotes.net/authors/zatende/posts/sending-emails-with-ease-a-step-by-step-guide-to-using-nodemailer-with-typescript-in-nextjs

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add an api function to send an email.
It works using the get if you type the api in the browser, not with the post by the way.

I'm also struggling to pass the vue options(mail, message etc) previously defined to the MailController.ts That's actually my main problem to custom the content of the email with the form fields from the .vue.

**MailController.ts**

```
    import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
    import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
    
    export const postMail = async (req: Request, res: Response,next: NextFunction) : Promise <any> => {
      //const complexes  = await dataSource.getRepository(Complex).find()
    
      const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
              service: 'Gmail',
              secure: true,
              port: 587,
              auth: {
                  user: '@gmail.com',
                  pass: 'zazabrdcvhdogskg'
              }
          })
      
       const mailOptions = {
            from: 'xxx <xxx@gmail.com>',
            to: 'xxx@gmail.com',
            subject: ' xxx : new inquiry !",',
            text: "alo",
            html: "<b>Node.js</b> New world for me"+
                  "<b>Node.js</b> New world for me"
    
      }
    
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, res) {
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log('Email Sent');
            }
        })
    
    
    }
```

**MailRouter.ts**

```
    import { Router } from 'express' import { postMail } from '../../controllers/MailController.js'
    
    const mailRouterVersion1 = Router()
    
    mailRouterVersion1.post('/mail', postMail);
    
    export default mailRouterVersion1enter code here
```

And my app.ts looks like this :

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { getManager, getRepository } from 'typeorm';
import  express from "express";
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { createExpressServer } from "routing-controllers";
import history from "connect-history-api-fallback"
import cors from "cors";

import releaseRouterVersion1 from "./routers/v1/ReleaseRouter.js"
import componentRouterVersion1 from "./routers/v1/ComponentRouter.js"
import interactionRouterVersion1 from "./routers/v1/InteractionRouter.js"
import complexRouterVersion1 from "./routers/v1/ComplexRouter.js"
import mailRouterVersion1 from "./routers/v1/MailRouter.js"

const app = express();
const port = 3000
const api = "/api/v1" /* Manually switch api */

app.use(express.json());

const corsOrigin ={
    origin: '*',
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    credentials:true,            
    optionSuccessStatus:200
}

app.use(cors(corsOrigin));
// Manage API versioning.
app.use(api,releaseRouterVersion1);
app.use(api,componentRouterVersion1);
app.use(api,interactionRouterVersion1);
app.use(api,complexRouterVersion1);
app.use(api,mailRouterVersion1);

app.use(history());
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with this and it works. I think it could be better but still.

**onSubmit in the vue :**

```
const onSubmit = async (): Promise<void> => {

  messageReturned.value = ""

   // POST request using fetch with async/await
  const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ 
        name: name.value , 
        email: email.value ,
        ligand: ligand.value,
        receptor: receptor.value,
        publication: publication.value,
        origin : origin.value,
        text :  text.value      
      })
  };

  messageReturned.value = "Your mail has been sent successfully ! Thanks."

  await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/mail', requestOptions);

};
```

In the **MailController.ts** I got something like this...

```
export const postMail = async (req: Request, res: Response,next: NextFunction) : Promise <void> => {
      
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
          service: 'Gmail',
          secure: true,
          port: 587,
          auth: {
              user: '@gmail.com',
              //pass: 'cicekhnmtfjsaxvy',//
              pass: 'zazabrdcvhdogskg'
          }
      })
  
   const mailOptions = {
        from: 'X <x@gmail.com>',
        to: 'jclab.bioinfo@gmail.com,'+req.body.email,
        subject: ' fsdf : new inquiry !",',
        html: "<b>From:</b> "+req.body.name+"<br>"+
              "<b>Ligand:</b> "+req.body.ligand+"<br>"+
              "<b>Receptor:</b> "+req.body.receptor+"<br>"+
              "<b>Origin:</b> "+req.body.ligand+"<br>"+  
              "<b>Publication:</b> "+req.body.publication+"<br>"+      
              "<b>Text:</b> "+req.body.text      
         
  }

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, res) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Email Sent');
        }
    })
```

Answer (score -2):

It seems you are trying to integrate Vue 3, Quasar, and Nodemailer to send emails upon form submission. Your code is on the right track, but there are a few corrections that need to be made.

1. **Import Statements:** Use ES6 import syntax for importing modules.
2. **Async/Await:** Since Nodemailer functions are asynchronous, use the `async` and `await` keywords properly.
3. **Transporter Configuration:** Place the transporter configuration inside the `try` block.
4. **Sending Email:** The code for sending the email should also be inside the `try` block.
5. **Message Handling:** Handle errors and success cases properly when sending emails.

**Make sure to replace "smtp.server", "your_email@example.com", and "your_password" with actual SMTP server details and your email credentials.**

This code should provide a more structured and functional approach to sending emails using Nodemailer within your Vue 3 application. It handles potential errors when sending emails and provides appropriate feedback to the user.

Here's a corrected version of your script section:

```js
<!-- Your template code remains unchanged -->

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useQuasar } from 'quasar'
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer'

const $q = useQuasar()
const name = ref<string | null>(null)
// ... (other variables)

const onSubmit = async () => {
  messageReturned.value = ""

  try {
    // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: "smtp.server",
      port: 587,
      secure: false,
      auth: {
        user: "your_email@example.com",
        pass: "your_password",
      },
    });

    // send mail with defined transport object
    await transporter.sendMail({
      from: '"SignalRdb Team " <your_email@example.com>',
      to: "recipient@example.com",
      subject: "Hello ✔",
      text: "Hello world?",
      html: "<b>Hello world?</b>",
    });

    messageReturned.value = "Your mail has been sent successfully! Thanks.";
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending email:", error);
    messageReturned.value = "An error occurred while sending the email.";
  }
};

// ... (other functions and variables)

</script>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
// Your style code remains unchanged
</style>
```

Comment: it doesn't work because it's not server side.